# What requirements does my function need here?

Tags: calculus, integration

Let's define $$f(x)=\int_a^{h(x)}g(y)dy.$$ for some $a\in\mathbb R$ and some continuous function $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. What requirements do I need for the function $h:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ other than differentiability to do the following:

We can define the function $$F:x\mapsto\int_a^xg(y)dy$$ and then say $f(x)=(h\circ F)(x)$, thus $$f'(x)=F'(h(x))\cdot h'(x).$$But I'm sure this isn't always possible. Does $h$ need to be monotone on some interval? Or bigger than $a$? Or is this really always possible?

Comment: $h$ has a continuous derivative is sufficient. See the relevant wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

Comment: So the derivative needs to be continuous as well?

Comment: Seems like continuous derivative is not necessary since the chain rule holds wherever $h$ and $F$ are differentiable. So $h$ is differentiable is sufficient.

Comment: Alright, thanks!